# i try to store file to folder after upload but not working

Tags: php, sql, file, post, upload

this code perfectly working at localhost but after upload online the data are store in database but file con't to be store on the folder.

declare the image

```
//Property image
$cimage=$_FILES["image"]["name"];
$extension1 = substr($cimage,strlen($cimage)-4,strlen($cimage));
```

allowed extensions

```
$allowed_extensions = array(".jpg",".jpeg",".png",".gif");
```

validation

```
    // Validation for allowed extensions .in_array() function `searches an array for a specific value.`
if(!in_array($extension1,$allowed_extensions))
{
echo "<script>alert('Image has Invalid format. Only jpg / jpeg/ png /gif format allowed');</script>";
}

else
{
```

File directory is images/cimage

retitle images

```
$image=($cimage);   
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"images/cimage".$image);
$ret="select title from property where title=:title";
 $query= $dbh -> prepare($ret);
$query->bindParam(':title',$title,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query-> execute();


$results = $query -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

 if($query -> rowCount() == 0)
```

Comment: check the `images/cimage` folder permission in your server. and set the 777 permission and check it

Comment: this is windows server

Comment: and all permission is ok

Comment: look at the server error log, the problem will be described there. i think it is in directory path, ```images``` is not in the executing script current directory.